# Comparing cells of one range to another using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am in a situation where I have to compare each cells of a particular column from Sheet1 to eache cells of a particular column of Sheet2. For example cells of Column B to be compared with cells of Column G of Sheet2 and when the cell matches then Column I and Column J of Sheet1 will be replaced with the value of Column G and Column H respectively...

I have done the following coding which is solving my issue...

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

lastRowi = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

For Each l In ws1.Range("E2:E" & lastRowi)
    For Each c In ws2.Range("G2:G" & lastRowj)
          If l.Cells.Value = c.Cells.Value And l.Cells.Value <> "" Then
            l.Cells.Offset(0, 3).Value = c.Cells.Offset(0, -1).Value
            l.Cells.Offset(0, 4).Value = c.Cells.Offset(0, 0).Value
            l.Cells.Offset(0, 5).Value = c.Cells.Offset(0, 1).Value

        End If
    Next c
Next l
```

But this code is taking time and for large rows its getting hanged. I think storing the data in Array and comparing will take lesser time...on achieving this am trying the following code which is giving error:

```
    Dim arr As Variant

arr = ws1.Range("B2:B" & lastRowi)

Dim varr As Variant
varr = ws2.Range("G2:G" & lastRowj)



For Each l In arr
    For Each c In varr
          If l.Cells.Value = c.Cells.Value And l.Cells.Value <> "" Then
            l.Cells.Offset(0, 3).Value = c.Cells.Offset(0, -1).Value
            l.Cells.Offset(0, 4).Value = c.Cells.Offset(0, 0).Value
            l.Cells.Offset(0, 5).Value = c.Cells.Offset(0, 1).Value

        End If
    Next c
Next l
```

Can anyone please on this am stuck to this problem quiet a long

Answer (score 0):

You can loop just through one sheet cells. For each cell do find on the other sheet. Should be quicker.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
lastRow1 = 14
With ws1
    For r = 2 To lastRow1
        Set HitRange = Nothing
        Set HitRange = ws2.Columns(7).Find(.Cells(r, 5).Value)
        If Not HitRange Is Nothing And .Cells(r, 5).Value <> "" Then
            .Cells(r, 6) = ws2.Cells(HitRange.Row, 6)
            .Cells(r, 7) = ws2.Cells(HitRange.Row, 7)
            .Cells(r, 8) = ws2.Cells(HitRange.Row, 8)
        End If
    Next
End With
```